# Spring JPA NullPointerException in query with EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I try to run a Query with EntityManager but every time I run this query in JPA console I get a NullPointerException.

But when I run this Query directly in database it works.

```
@Repository
@Slf4j
public class MyCredentialRepositoryImpl implements MyCredentialRepository {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public Set<PublicKeyCredentialDescriptor> getCredentialIdsForUsername(String username) {
        Query query1 = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT UserEntity.id FROM UserEntity");
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the stacktrace when I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1218) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:374) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:343) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:277) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:385) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:366) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:659) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1146) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2300) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2241) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:589) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:317) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:716) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:368) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
...
...
```

I can not find the mistake and what could be missing in my code

Comment: Have you created bean for entity manager?

Comment: Do I need this? Because when I call this.entityManager.toString() I don't get null.

Comment: You're missing quite a bit of information. My best guess would be your entity is not well formed against your table in your database. I'm not a JPA expert myself in any case. Also, `UserEntity.id` seems unnecessary. I won't say it's a problem though.

Comment: which line in your code is throwing NPE? did u try to debug?

Comment: Try using UserEntity.Id instead of UserEntity.id. Not sure what upper/lower case you have for i/I in your id/Id in your UserEntity. You can also try toLower. Can you post your UserEntity here if possible?

Comment: @searchengine27 my Entity has the same fields as the table in my database. But you were right, I have to delete UserEntity in UserEntity.id then it works. But this was a reduced example of my problem because I want to run `SELECT CredentialEntity.id FROM CredentialEntity INNER JOIN UserEntity ON UserEntity.id = CredentialEntity.user.id WHERE UserEntity.username = :username`. There I can not remove CredentialEntity in front of id. Do you know how I have to write that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I put in the comments the first part, but I'm going to put an answer instead so the comments don't get out of control and into a conversation.

First part being the change from `UserEntity.id` to `id`.

Second part you've asked in the comments, which is that you need to have some sort of identifier because of a join, which I'm actually not even sure is true. For clarity to readers, the part placed in the comment by the OP is

```
SELECT CredentialEntity.id FROM CredentialEntity
INNER JOIN UserEntity ON UserEntity.id = CredentialEntity.user.id
WHERE UserEntity.username = :username
```

So based on this, it looks like you have an embedded ID, which is your problem. You have to provide the embedded field name along with the field inside of the embeddable, such as

```
SELECT foo.user.id FROM CredentialEntity foo ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @searchengine27 commented I have to write

`Query query1 = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT id FROM UserEntity");`

instead of

`Query query1 = this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT UserEntity.id FROM UserEntity");`

This was an easier example of my problem because I wanted to run a inner join. So in the following I will post my old code and after that the code how it works:

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT CredentialEntity.id FROM CredentialEntity INNER JOIN UserEntity ON UserEntity.id = CredentialEntity.user.id WHERE UserEntity.username = :username");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
```

This Code works:

```
Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT c.id FROM CredentialEntity c INNER JOIN UserEntity u ON u.id = c.user.id WHERE u.username = :username");
```